# Placing part of a group onscreen at any resolution

Tags: coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK in **zoomEven** mode.

I have a `group` called *topGroup* that contains:

- an image;
- just below the image, a button;

The group must be placed totally offscreen, except for the button, whose position must (for any resolution/device) always be the same as the top of the screen.

What I want to avoid is having this button cut someway for resolution/device reasons, so I want to perfeclty see it at any resolution and its top must be the same as the top of the screen.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `button.y = -0.5 * button.contentHeight` (using `contentHeight` rather than `height` lets you scale the button first if needed) and `topGroup.y = 0`, the origin of the group will be at the top of the display (whatever the display dimensions) and the button should stick out into the visible area.

You can then change/transition the topGroup y coordinate to bring the image portion into view.

Comment: Hi, if I set topGroup.y to 0, won't the group be quite entirely visible? I didn't set any anchorY, am I supposed to change that too?

Comment: The coordinates of DisplayObjects added to a  GroupObject are in the coordinates of the group.  Setting the position of the group sets the origin of this coordinate system. No need to set anchor points in that case.

Comment: @goojaiiGreg: setting anchorX and Y lets you work way better  :-)